# Play anorm 2.3 - 2.4 migration

Tags: playframework, anorm

When migrating to play 2.4 I noticed the following:

1/apply is deprecated on SqlQuery - ok - I looked at the provided implementation :

```
def go(c: Option[Cursor], s: Stream[Row]): Stream[Row] = c match {
      case Some(cursor) => go(cursor.next, s :+ cursor.row)
      case _ => s
    }
```

Isn't that appending each element to a Stream which time is proportional to the size of stream? eg doesn't that end up being n2? The previous implementation used  cons I think...

2/SqlQuery("qry") used to have a way to not parse the query - That seems to have been removed

I have a use case with a query executed often (like 1000qps) and that I cannot cache once : it looks like select X,Y,Y from `dbname`.db - So no bindable statement for database name. For a large query it turns out the statement parser is somewhat slow - Is there a way to explicitly say: I don't need that query parsed?

3/ResultSetParser has gone totally private - I had a util function that provided:

```
def vector[A](p: RowParser[A]): ResultSetParser[Vector[A]] ...
```

because I prefer Vector - I used that with SQL("...").as 
Any suggestion as to how to replace? withResult maybe?

Comment: You can find a migration doc online: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Anorm

Comment: please do share your findings on the migration - i think a lot of people will be interested

Answer (score 0):

*1.* The current implementation of `.apply` is there only for backward compatibility, as deprecated. If you want to do streaming, you can have a look at the Streaming support: `.withResult`, `.foldWhile`

*2.* Constructing directly the underlying query types (`SqlQuery`) is no longer allowed, as it would bypass some checks done while using the public constructor `SQL(...)` (or SQL interpolation `SQL"..."`). Nothing prevent from keeping a query init'ed in this way to re-use it with different parameters.

```scala
val baseQuery = SQL("SELECT * FROM Test WHERE id = {id}")
val query1 = baseQuery.on("id" -> "foo")
val query2 = baseQuery.on("id" -> "bar")
```

*3.* As said on the issue tracker, the `ResultSetParser` was not designed to be a general purpose type, but for internal use in Anorm implementation. Unsealing it would have a maintenance impact.

You can either get a `Vector` from a `List` (`.*` or `.+` parsers), or use Streaming support to build the vector by yourself without intermediary list.

Comment: Please be constructive and read the doc. *1* The backward compatibility of Play requires the function to be still there, even if you consider it suboptimal. You are free of using the new Streaming support, or to discuss of improvement on the MailingList. *2*. As said, nothing prevent to keep the query prepared from `SQL`, to run it several time with different parameter set. BTW the SQL interpolation was introduced in 2.3 for performance improvements.

Comment: Hi - Sorry did not mean to be non constructive - I remain a fan of anorm, best SQL lib in the scala world!!- Though I think the current impl of apply could cause unforeseen perf. problem in a prod server, if ones goes over large resultSet. I did indeed abandon it and switched to withResult - As for SQL interpolation like I was saying I'm happy with its perf, it's better for my particular use case...